# z-index doesn't work with floating div

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a structure like this:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='cell'>aaaa</div>
    <div class='cell'>bbbb</div>
    <div class='cell'>cccc</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='cell'>dddd</div>
    <div class='cell'>eeee</div>
    <div class='cell'>ffff</div>
</div>
```

with the related style sheet:

```
.cell {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 82px;
}

.cell:hover {
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}

row {
    clear: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I would simply that the div above the cursor get resized maintaining fixed the structure of the rest of div.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting a negative right margin of -18px on the hovered cell (100-82=18):

```
.cell:hover {
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: -18px;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/DNsmb/)

Comment: Quite near to solution... that's how it looks in my example, don't know why, but it seems that z-index works conversely http://jsfiddle.net/Pedrozena/AtfgW/

Comment: ok, solved orizontal behavior.. now I have some issues with vertical behavior.. that's what i get: http://jsfiddle.net/Pedrozena/ZjvT2/  It works except for the fact that the div of another row stays still over and not under the selected div

Comment: Ok, finaly solved... That's the solution. Thanks a lot! http://jsfiddle.net/Pedrozena/ZjvT2/1/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the class for `row`.

If you change your class in css from `row` into `.row`:

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/DKWuZx8r)***

Class **must** start with a `.` e.g. `.anyname`

Class (in HTML) `<div class="james"></div>` are accessed with `.james` in css

ID's (in html) `<div id="james"></div>` are accessed with `#james` in CSS

Comment: Though he indeed made a coding error, I don't think this is what he meant: user wants to maintain div structure (eg the hovered cell should grow, but not mess up the layout), see my answer below.